# How to install python-gpgme ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dropbox, aptitude

I installed Dropbox but when I run it. I get an error saying:

```
In order to use dropbox you need proprietary daemons. Install python-gpgme.
```

Then, I headed over to installation of that python module from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/python-gpgme/download) but there its written use aptitude or synaptic to install packages which is generally considered a safe and easy way. How to use aptitude to install this python-gpgme? I use apt-get and never used aptitude. Help me to install it.

Comment: I downloaded from here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/python-gpgme and made the instalation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** It's better to let the OS manage updates then downloading manually downloading and installing apps. [Have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`aptitude`, `apt-get`, `synaptic` are all front ends. You can use any of them:

- `apt-get install python-gpgme`
- `aptitude install python-gpgme`
- (some GUI method for Synaptic)

From 17.10, `python-gpgme` has been deprecated and replaced by `python-gpg`. Use that as the package name instead.

Comment: Update for Ubuntu 18.04: python-gpgme is obsolete, replaced by python-gpg. This dropbox message is a known 'bug': https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1759984